# Excel compare columns input third

Tags: excel, merge, spreadsheet, columnsorting

I have tried several things and am four hours into non working formulas. I'm in grad school but very beginning of using Excel for calculations.

I want to take data on one sheet (sheet 1) and match one column of it (zip code [column A]) to a second sheet (sheet 2) zip code [column A] and income [column B]. 
I need to be able to associate zip codes and all other associated data from sheet 1 (survey info) with income (from sheet 2) to analyze it.

Comment: Your first paragraph is utterly unnecessary. Now about the second paragraph, you just mentioned what you are trying to do. You didn't say what you `really did`. Please read #3 in http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

My favored solution is to use the VLOOKUP function. I've used this many times when a doing a lookup-type operation.

=VLOOKUP( zip, sheet2 range, column in sheet2 range of zip, FALSE )

The first parameter is the value you want to look up (sheet 1 zip code). The second parameter is the table to use for the lookup (a range from sheet 2). The last parameter is the column number from the lookup range (sheet 2) you're interested in. The last parameter indicates that you want an exact match, not closest match.

You do need to make sure that zip code is the first column.